# Winsock - Receive packet twice

Tags: c++, c, windows, winsock, winsock2

Is there some way that I could, trough Winsock, receive a packet without actually blocking other listeners from receiving it too?

If I use recv then I can only capture a packet once, but I would need it to be captured by multiple listeners.

So, is this possible?

Comment: Not with TCP/IP, which is a peer-to-peer protocol. You might want to consider UDP, which can do broadcasts (but which does not guarantee delivery).

Comment: Have one listener and forward the messages to other interested parties?

Comment: Multiple listeners in the same process? You want messaging throughout your program for that, decoupled from networking. Or multiple listeners on different TCP/IP endpoints? Be _specific_.